# Issue with promise chain

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';

export function createHttpObservable(url: string) {
    console.log('Url is', url);
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.json());
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(body => {
            observer.next(body);
            observer.complete();
        })
        .catch(err => observer.error(err));
    });
}
```

I am not able to figure out why in above code the execution does not move to second then block. The browser console logs is as follows.

[image]

However if i remove the line **console.log(response.json());**, the code works fine. May be it is a very basic question, but somehow i am not able to figure out. If you know, please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: `response.json()` is a *promise*, why did you want to log it anyway?

Comment: if you're trying to debug this, I'd first set `const resp = response.json();` then do `console.log(resp);  return resp`.   I can't find the documentation, but I believe `response.json()` resolves the promise (double check that), and that's why the second `then` statement is not executing with your given code.

Comment: Are you asking *why* the console.log breaks the code, or how can you fix this? B/c the fact that 'response.json()' returns a promise is not the real reason why the code breaks.

Comment: If you're using Angular, why aren't you using [Angular's HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http)?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Response#body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/body) is a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream). A stream can be consumed only once and then It's empty. Since the `Body#json()` method [reads the stream to completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), the second time you try to use the same body, you are tapping into an empty stream. That's why the `Response` API implementation locks the stream and doesn't allow to call the method twice.

You can try It yourself:

```js
const a = new ReadableStream();
const b = new Response(a);

b.json(); // returns a Promise
b.json(); // TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, you can mark it as an answer. Your question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `response.json()` locks the resouce so the second call will fail.

**You should avoid calling it twice** but if you really want to see the result there I would advice you using this code:

```
   required here
       \/
.then(async response => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(await response.clone().json()); // read json result from cloned response
    return response.json();
})
```

or simply log it in the second `then`:

```
.then(async response => {
   console.log(response);
   return response.json();
 })
.then(body => { 
   console.log(body); // it doesn't require any workarounds
   observer.next(body);
   observer.complete();
})
```